# Cannot start Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have several virtual machines deployed in Azure West Europe Data center. I am trying to start these machines but it keeps in the starting state forever.
Tried to stop the machine using Azure Powershell cmdlets but it fails.
Tried to change VM configuration and start the VM but failed.

Any help or info on why is this hapenning? It was working normally till yesterday and I was able to start and stop VM's using powershell normally.

Thank you,

Comment: This might happen when there is some run time error in your start up code also.

Comment: They started up today. I think this datacenter had a problem yesterday

Comment: are you using Azure Resource Manager ?